# Prove A = $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$ using the distributive and associative law.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know how to prove this using an element and subset proof but that's not what I'm being asked to do. I'm suppose to prove it using the distributive law and the associative law but I'm just not seeing how to do this. Can you give me some advice on how to start this. I figure the first thing would be $$((A \cup B) \cap A) \cup ((A \cup B) \cap B^c))$$ But I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Doesn't look right. Do you mean $A=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$?

Comment: @HowDoIMath Yes got my cap and cup confused!

Comment: @mconn7 Oh, I hope you don't ever do that while drinking a hot coffee on a sunny morning. $\ddot{\smile}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing I would do is to notice that by the distributive law, we have

$$(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c) = A \cap (B \cup B^c).$$

You also know that $B\cup B^c$ is equal to the universal set.

Comment: Oh wow I feel really dumb. I was looking at it like you could only go one way the distributive law! That makes so much sense! Thank you!

Comment: @mconn7 no problem, I'm glad it makes sense.